# In mysql one trigger calling another trigger that updates the first triggers calling table gives an error. how to resolve?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables books (id,title,numofcopies), borrows (bookid,id,issuedt,returndt,duedt), claims (bookid,id). Books stores book details, borrows stores borrowing details, claims stores details for users who want a particular book but it is unavailable for some reason therefore their details are stored in this table. What i want is as soon as a book is returned (i.e. a deletion occurs from borrows table) its 'numofcopies' increases by 1 in the books table then if this book is 'claimed' by someone insert the corresponding information in borrows table i.e issue the book to that person. I implemented following triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `issue` AFTER INSERT ON `borrows`
FOR EACH ROW begin  
update books set numofcopies = numofcopies - 1 where books.bookid = new.bookid;
end 

CREATE TRIGGER `retbook` AFTER DELETE ON `borrows`
FOR EACH ROW begin  
update books set numofcopies = numofcopies + 1 where books.bookid = old.bookid;
end


CREATE TRIGGER `claimtr` AFTER UPDATE ON `books`
FOR EACH ROW begin
declare done int default false;
declare vbookid varchar (10);
declare vid varchar (10);
declare var1 CURSOR FOR select bookid,id from claims where claims.bookid = new.bookid order by dateofclaim ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
open var1;
fetch var1 into vbookid,vid;
if( new.numofcopies > 1)
  then
  if ( done = false)
    then  
    delete from request where request.id = vid and request.bookid = vbookid;
    insert into borrows (id,bookid,issuedt) values (vid, vbookid, now());
  end if;
end if;
end
```

All triggers have been created successfully but when i delete an entry from borrows i get the following error:

```
 error 1442:Can't update table 'borrows' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I cant think of any other way to do this please help!

Comment: Would it be clearer to do this in code? One could argue keeping all your businesslogic in code is a better way because it will be clear what actions a returned book start, and that way you can avoid this error. Just do what you described, but in code instead of triggers and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Nanne I want to automate the whole process. And this is the backend of my application. What i want is after a deletion request from the front end all of this should happen automatically.

Comment: @Nanne Thanx I understood, what you meant, quite later. I used a stored procedure to overcome the problem. Now its all good